# Finding total energy for RC discharged capacitor at t = ∞?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors, switches

Most Rc circuits are not as severely difficult as this kind of circuit. I'm trying to solve for both the time constant and the voltage V2 across the R2 resistor, both of which will hold the necessary values needed to find the total energy for the capacitor. 
[image]
However, despite knowing that the time constant is RC, I'm uncertain as to whether I ended up with the right equivalent resistance, Req, that's used to find the time constant. I was under the assumption that with the modified approach I took to find Req, it came out to be 5000 ohms, leading to a time constant of 25 ms. I'm almost certain this part is done right.
[image]
For (b), I understood that because a discharging capacitor is involved, the initial voltage for the capacitor would be zero: vc(0-) = 0, such that it would equal vc(t=0), based on the given assumption. Unfortunately, beyond this, I am stuck on where to proceed next in finding vc(0+), V0 (initial voltage) and other key variables needed to solve for V2. My instinct tells me that finding the voltage across the capacitor, Vc(t) is likely to be needed for (c), but I could be wrong about that. For an RC circuit with a discharged capacitor, I am still confused as to how to approach this circuit. And then there is finding the total energy of the capacitor, which I believe is dependent on the voltage across capacitor too?

Comment: You need to find the Thevenin equivalent resistance with the switch closed. It's obviously higher than 3K because there  is 3K in series with the capacitor. Short out the voltage source and redraw it- the calculation can be done in your head.

Comment: Don't be distracted by R3 being drawn diagonally - it's in parallel with R2. When you've redrawn the circuit, simplifying the R4/R5/R6 configuration is easy.

Comment: Indeed, I believe this to be true, upon redrawing the circuit diagram. The R4 || (R5 + R6) configuration turned out to be in parallel to (R2 || R3), leaving out R1 as being in series with all of that. However, considering that the circuit is redrawn, wouldn't I have to re-draw the original circuit again (after the switch is closed) to find out the voltage for the resistor? Because while I did end up with a Req ~5k, the capacitor would become an open circuit as t goes to infinity, right?

Comment: For t = ∞ you don't need RC or Req.

Answer (score 2):

Apply a sanity check, the cap is in series with a resistor R1, so Req clearly cannot be less then the 3k series resistance....

I would start by rolling R4,5,6 up into one resistor, and then combining R2,3 into a single resistor, just to simplify the thing (Resistors in series and parallel).

Then for B (and maybe it is just me) I would convert the 1V voltage source in series with a resistor to a current source in parallel with a resistor, which at T0+ ends up in parallel with R2.... Combine with R2 and convert back to voltage source in series with resistor, at which point you have 1 loop of three series connected components (plus voltage source), should be soluble from there I would have thought?

Hint, once you have that little series network, solve for current then calculate the relevant voltage.

Comment: Yes, I came to understand that the Req is definitely more than 3k ohms, and after practicing your configuration of the R4/R5/R6 resistors and the R2/R3 parallel resistors, that confirmed it.

Comment: However, I am confused about the approach you mentioned for (b). From what I understand, you're suggesting on building the Thevenin equivalent of the circuit for t = 0+, because with including the voltage source and the resistors, Kirchoff voltage law can be used to find the current source, which lead to the voltage across resistor R2. But doesn't this only account for the t > 0 case? Is the voltage across the capacitor not relevant?

Comment: Try this reasoning: At T0, the cap has zero voltage across it, so R1 is in parallel with R2, making Vr2(0) = 1.5k/7.5k = 0.2V. After many time constants the cap is fully charged so you can ignore R1, making the voltage across R2 a simple potential divider problem, between these two conditions you have an exponential rise given by the timeconstant of the circuit. Where I was going with the Thevenin  and then Norton transforms was ending up with a series circuit but whatever works.

Comment: Ah, I see where you're going with that: So I do get the fact that the cap, having 0 terminal voltage, acts as a short-circuit, making R1||R2. But I'm puzzled as to how you ended up with Vr2(0) = 0.2 V? Did you perhaps simplify the circuit down by combining all the resistors via parallel/series into a single loop to find that? Also, as you said, at t=0+, the cap meets is fully charged (1V) and becomes an open circuit. So from that point, is that the reason why R1 is neglected?

Comment: Fully charged is NOT 1V because you have a series combination of R2 || R3 and that mess on the right (R4/5/6). I got 0.2V from R1 || R2 || R3 = 1.5k, R4,5,6 simplifies to 6k, so 1V * 1.5k/(1.5k + 6k) = 1/5 = 0.2V. For the fully charged case you can ignore R1, as there is no current flowing in it if dV/dT~=0, so you get R2 || R3 = 3k, hence T0+ gets you 1V * 3k/(3k+ 6k) = 1/3V as the terminal condition. You know the timeconstant so just write the expression for Vr2(t). Pay attention to the polarity of that voltage source.

Comment: Oh dear, I believe you're right: my line of thinking did not account for the influx of resistors that have their own contributing voltages, so it most definitely cannot simply end up as 1V. Okay, so with that reasoning of R1 being neglected due to no current is one that I can understand on a fundamental level. I'll admit that the polarity of the voltage source did throw me quite a bit until re-framing the circuit with R2||R3 for t=0+. But for the fully charged case, if the cap reaches its final voltage, as Vc(0+), how can we even find that value then?

Comment: Apologies for the last question I asked, as it was an unclear question! Instead, if I want to find the total energy delivered to the capacitor for t>0, would I now have to focus on finding the energy of the capacitor for t=0 and t=infinity, and then take the difference of those two? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You know the voltage across the cap at T0 is 0 and in fact know the voltage across the cap at any time > 0 because you know the time constant and the voltage for T0+, so write an expression for the capacitor voltage and substitute into  E=1/2CV^2.

Comment: Oh! I see! Okay, so the cap having 0 V at T0 is what I understand definitely. However, for what you mentioned about the voltage across the cap at t>0, when calculating that voltage, are we to ignore the R1 resistor only? Or is that perhaps a false statement?

Comment: Because if I recall, the cap acts as an open circuit at t = infinity too right? But R1 is in series with too so I don't know for sure what happens to that resistor at steady state?

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding why the voltage of the capacitor is not 1 V at t = infinity. The cap isn't parallel to Vr2(t), even if R1 is supposedly disregarded, but rather it's in series with V1. If, for the T0+ condition, 1/3V is the terminal voltage for the (R2||R3) resistor, then 2/3V should be the voltage for the (R4|| (R5 + R6)) then. Is there something that I'm perhaps missing?

Comment: @Heavywake draw the final simplified circuit with ground on the bottom and all resistors simplified as much as possible. You will clearly see why the cap is not at 1V.

Comment: @mkeith Are you perhaps referring to the case where t = infinity? Because I did draw a final simplified circuit as a single loop, with the 1V voltage source and a combined 2k ohm resistor (without the R1 resistor). From what I do see, the cap acts as a open circuit, but the problem is that I don't know if R1 is nonexistant for this case, as it is in series with R1, from what Dan mentioned. And since the cap does carry its terminal voltage, the voltage should be less than 1V, since the combined resistor carries a voltage as well. Is there maybe a fault in this approach?

Comment: @DanMills So apparently, after some re-reading on how resistors operate and how they change with respect to open circuits, I came to realize that with no current running through the cap upon the path of the R1 resistor, the R1 resistor can actually be disregarded (upon the circuit reaching steady state at t = infinity). With that said, would it be wrong of me to conclude that the voltage across the capacitor is the sum of V1 + Vr2 + Voltage of (R4||(R5 + R6)?

Comment: With the thing settled to steady state there is no current flowing in the capacitor, hence no voltage developed across R1 (Because there is no current) so the voltage across the cap MUST be equal to Vr2 at this point. You really need to be discussing this stuff with your lecturer because I think there are some fairly fundamental misunderstandings about how circuits, voltage and current work that you need to fix, and fixing them is much easier in a face to face with your tutor then it is over the internet. Stack overflow is not a good venue for tutorials on very basic concepts.

Comment: @Heavywake, draw the circuit with the following modifications: 1) replace the switch with a short circuit (ignore the switch and assume it is ON).  2) simplify all resistor combinations as much as possible to reduce the number of resistors. 3) Keep the capacitor in the circuit. 4) Keep the voltage source in the circuit. 5) Designate the - terminal of the supply as ground, and draw it physically below all of the components.